# Handle copying angular node_modules in Sails

Tags: sails.js

Is it Ok, to copy dependencies i.e `AngularJs` from `node_modules` folder to assets folder in SailsJs? If yes, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem at all. Just copy it from `node_modules` and put it in `assets/dependencies` or whatever that meet your needs.